# Installing NPAPI plugin for google chrome and mozilla firefox

Tags: plugins

Please provide me the steps to install NPAPI plugin in Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

My need is to enable ActiveXcontrol in google chrome and firefox as it is eneabled in IE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox, place your plugin in the FireFox installation folder under a new/existing folder called "plugins", then restart FireFox and it should then be read to use.

Google Chrome does not support ActiveX and neither does FireFox.  If you need to do advanced functionality, use your plugin.

For Google Chrome, try placing the plugin file in the installation folder or a folder called "Extensions" in the installation folder and then restart the browser.

Hope this helps.